# jQuery hover show div toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, toggle

I'm working on this pretty easy site but it's been a while since I fiddled with jQuery and I think I'm doing something wrong here.

Here you can preview the idea with jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rGb34/1/

There are a few problems with the jQuery.

1. If you hover over the yellow button the yellow content starts toggling.
2. If you hover over a button and then back off it the div disapears (due to the toggle function) but I would like to have the last div active even when there's no hover.

Does anyone have a good tip for me so I can finish this?

Comment: I am not sure if i correctly understood this - is this what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/RPMSZ/ ? I left out the css. Also, please pay attention to the unqieness of the more important ids of the dom elements :) i suppose you confused classes with ids.

Comment: Umm.. id's should be unique.. it looks like you have your `id` and `class` mixed up since your classes are unique and your id are the same for all four divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Don't use same id name with another tag. In your example it was id="slider" .

[Here is jsFiddle to play with (I have edited your html and css too)](http://jsfiddle.net/rGb34/18/)

You can do that with this way, much more solid:

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.greenC, .blueC, .orangeC').hide();

    $('.nav li').hover(function() {
        var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
       // takes class hovered element. example: '.yellow'

        $('.slider').hide();
        $('.'+ takeClass + 'C').show();// shows the element '.yellowC'
    });

});​
```

And your html should be like this:

```
<div class="yellowC slider">...</div>
<div class="greenC slider">...</div>
<div class="blueC slider">...</div>
<div class="orangeC slider">...</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
     <li class="yellow"><a href="./" class="y_button">Fiducairy services</a></li>
     <li class="green"><a href="./" class="g_button">Licensing</a></li>
     <li class="blue"><a href="./" class="b_button">Payment processing</a></li>
     <li class="orange"><a href="./" class="o_button">E-zone colocation</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

Comment: Wauw that looks like a very nice piece of code. Can you maybe explain what that "takeclass" does in the takeClass + 'C' because the classnmes allready have a C at the end?

Comment: yeap, you can change that whatever you want, just need to match them on jQuery.

Comment: inspect html carefuly= container: <div class="yellowC slider"> and nav: <li class="yellow">, i match them on jQuery when nav element hovered.

Comment: Ah like that! That is very smart. Thanks a lot, you made me realize I need to brush up on programming again.

Comment: np mate, im glad i could help (:

Answer (score 0):

$('.green, .blue, .orange, .yellow').hide(); if you hide yellow also, it works fine for me..is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `div` to show up properly on load, you have to be more specific on your `.yellow` event handler

```
$('.y_active, .yellow').hover(
function() {
    $('.yellow').show();
    $('.green').hide();
    $('.blue').hide();
    $('.orange').hide();
}, function() {
    $('.yellow').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Br8gV/)