# jQuery tabs, link to another tab from inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have [jQuery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and I would like to be able to open a tab from a link (inside or outside the current tab or page)

It does work if the link is in an external page and looks like this:

```
http://server.com/view.php?id=130#section-2
```

This correctly open the tab "section-2"

The problem is when the link is in the same page, it does not refresh the page (as it just add the #section-2) so the tab is not selected.

I saw some answers example using ids in the  tag and binding the click in jQuery, but I cannot use this because some of my links are computed and I don't know if they are pointing to inside or outside.

Comment: jQuery ui is a heavy libary, you can write your own simple tabs script and do whatever you want. Check this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724962/jquery-hover-show-div-toggle/11725216#11725216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the id "section-2-link" to the  tags linked to the tabs (add the '-link' at the end to avoid having same id as the tab content). And then add this to js

```
jQuery(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "section-2")
    jQuery('#' + hash + '-link').trigger("click");
});
```

This detects when the hash on url changes and trigger the click on the link you need (to open the correct tab)